# Parallelize nested loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nested-loops, parfor

I'm trying to speed up the simulation of some panel data in **Matlab**. I have to simulate first over individuals (loop index ii from 1 to N) and then for each individual over age (loop index jj from 1 to JJ). The code is slow because inside the two loops there is a **bilinear interpolation** to do.

Since the iterations in the outer loop are independent, I tried to use **parfor** in the outer loop (the loop indexed by ii), but I get the error message "the parfor cannot run due to the way the variable hsim is used". Could someone explain why and how to solve the problem if possible? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
a_sim = zeros(Nsim,JJ);
h_sim = zeros(Nsim,JJ);
% Find point on a_grid corresponding to zero assets
aa0 = find_loc(a_grid,0.0);
% Zero housing
hh0 = 1;
a_sim(:,1) = a_grid(aa0);
h_sim(:,1) = h_grid(hh0);
parfor ii=1:Nsim !illegal
    for jj=1:JJ-1
        z_c = z_sim_ind(ii,jj);
        apol_interp = griddedInterpolant({a_grid,h_grid},apol(:,:,z_c,jj));
        hpol_interp = griddedInterpolant({a_grid,h_grid},hpol(:,:,z_c,jj));
        a_sim(ii,jj+1) = apol_interp(a_sim(ii,jj),h_sim(ii,jj));
        h_sim(ii,jj+1) = hpol_interp(a_sim(ii,jj),h_sim(ii,jj));
    end
end
```

Comment: Try creating a separate variable holding `h_sim(ii,:)` that the inner loop can read and update, and copy the result to `h_sim` as a separate reduction outside the inner loop.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for the tip but the complication is that the update of h_sim and a_sim is recursive. I cannot do all j's at the same time. In other words, the inner loop over j is *not* parallelizable

Comment: I noticed that the update is sequential.  All iterations of `jj` for a single value of `ii` need to share the same vector instance.  But there's no need for different inner loops (different `ii`) to work on the same matrix, they each can have and update their own little slice, and copy the final value of that slice into the big matrix after the `jj` loop finishes.

Comment: Try to permute the array dimensions: `a_sim(jj+1, ii)`. You want the outer loop to loop over the last array index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Ben Voigt's suggestion was correct. To spell it out, do something like this:

```
parfor ii=1:Nsim
    a_sim_row = a_sim(ii,:);
    h_sim_row = h_sim(ii,:);
    for jj=1:JJ-1
        z_c = z_sim_ind(ii,jj);
        apol_interp = griddedInterpolant({a_grid,h_grid},apol(:,:,z_c,jj));
        hpol_interp = griddedInterpolant({a_grid,h_grid},hpol(:,:,z_c,jj));
        a_sim_row(jj+1) = apol_interp(a_sim_row(jj),h_sim_row(jj));
        h_sim_row(jj+1) = hpol_interp(a_sim_row(jj),h_sim_row(jj));
    end
    a_sim(ii,:) = a_sim_row;
    h_sim(ii,:) = h_sim_row;
end
```

This is a fairly standard `parfor` pattern to work around the limitation (in this case, `parfor` cannot spot that what you're doing is not order-independent as far as the outer loop is concerned) - extract a whole slice, do whatever is needed, then put the whole slice back.

Comment: It works well, thanks! I get the warning that "the array apol is a broadcast variable and this may result in unnecessary overhead", same for hpol. I guess it is unavoidable though

Comment: You can pretty much ignore that message most of the time. Unless `apol` and `hpol` are massive, it's probably not worth trying to address - even if it is possible. Use `ticBytes` and `tocBytes` to get a feel for the amount of data transfer.